# how to solve this grammar error in matching "<<" in regex

Tags: regex, perl

so here's my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<DATA>)
{
if(m!<<("[a-z]+")!)
print $1;
}

__DATA__
case 0:cout<<"zero";return x;
case 1:cout<<"one";return x;
case 2:cout<<"two";return x;
case 3:cout<<"three";return x;
case 4:cout<<"four";return x;
case 5:cout<<"five";return x;
```

---

I do find problems in matching the `<<`.so how to deal with it? I want to match the
string "zero","two" and so on, but i failed.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you used to program in **C/C++** (guessing by reading the content of your `__DATA__` section). In those languages one could put rigth next to an `if (cond)` statement, an `instruction` (having a benefit in the reduction of compilation time).

In **Perl**, when `instruction` is not a `block` this is done by typing:

```
instruction if (cond);
```

If you want to write an `if (cond)` statement in the above mentioned *"C-like way"* you have to write `instruction` in a `block`, even if you've got only one `instruction`:

```
if (cond) {
  instruction;
}
```

So.. you could use:

```
print "$1\n"
  if (m!<<("[a-z]+")!);
```

as like as:

```
if (m!<<("[a-z]+")!) {
  print "$1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(<DATA>)
{
  print "$1\n" if /<<("\w+")/;
}
```

should match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($subject =~ m/<<(".*?")/si) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```